# How to authenticate a GitHub Actions workflow as a GitHub App so it can trigger other workflows?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, github-api, github-cli

By default (when using the default `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`) GitHub Actions [workflows can't trigger other workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow). So for example if a workflow sends a pull request to a repo that has a CI workflow that normally runs the tests on pull requests, the CI workflow won't run for a pull request that was sent by another workflow.

There are probably lots of other GitHub API actions that a workflow authenticating with the default `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` can't take either.

How can I authenticate my workflow runs as a GitHub App, so that they can trigger other workfows and take any other actions that I grant the GitHub App permissions for?

### Why not just use a personal access token?

The GitHub docs linked above recommend authenticating workflows using a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (PAT) to allow them to trigger other workflows, but PATs have some downsides:

- You probably don't want your workflow to authenticate as any human user's account because any pull requests, issues, etc created by the workflow will appear to have been created by that human rather than appearing to be automated. The PAT would also become a very sensitive secret because it would grant access to all repos that the human user's account has access to.
- You could create a [machine user](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users) account to own the PAT. But if you grant the machine user access to all repos in your organization then the PAT again becomes a very sensitive secret. You can add the machine user as a collaborator on only the individual repos that you need, but this is inconvenient because you'll always need to add the user to each new repo that you want it to have access to.
- Classic PATs have only broad-grained permissions. The recently-introduced [fine-grained PATs](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/) [don't work with GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6680) (which is the easiest way to send PRs, open issues, etc from workflows) and there's no ETA for when support will be added.

GitHub Apps offer the best balance of convenience and security for authenticating workflows: apps can have fine-grained permissions and they can be installed only in individual repos or in all of a user or organization's repos (including automatically installing the app in new repos when they're created). Apps also get a nice page where you can type in some docs ([example](https://github.com/apps/workflow-authentication-demo-app)), the app's avatar and username on PRs, issues, etc link to this page. Apps are also clearly labelled as "bot" on any PRs, issues, etc that they create.

This [third-party documentation](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/main/docs/concepts-guidelines.md#triggering-further-workflow-runs) is a good summary of the different ways of authenticating workflows and their pros and cons.

### I don't want to use a third-party GitHub Action

There are guides out there on the internet that will tell you how to authenticate a workflow as an app but they all tell you to use third-party actions (from the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions)) to do the necessary token exchange with the GitHub API. I don't want to do this because it requires sending my app's private key to a third-party action. I'd rather write (or copy-paste) my own code to do the token exchange.

Comment: I thought the background was useful to have, because I was thinking "PAT" and "machine user" immediately.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I've added back the explanation of why not to just use a PAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links:

- [Working demo repo](https://github.com/seanh/worfklow-authentication-demo)
- [Workflow that sends PRs](https://github.com/seanh/worfklow-authentication-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/send-pr.yml)
- [Example PR](https://github.com/seanh/worfklow-authentication-demo/pull/2) sent by the workflow (notice that the `ci.yml` workflow was automatically triggered on the PR)
- [Workflow run](https://github.com/seanh/worfklow-authentication-demo/actions/runs/3876563440/jobs/6610549741) that sent the PR

To create a GitHub App and a workflow that authenticates as that app and sends PRs that can trigger other workflows:

1. [Create a GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/creating-a-github-app) in your user or organization account. Take note of your app's **App ID** which is shown on your app's settings page, you'll need it later.
2. [Grant your app the necessary permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/managing-github-apps/editing-a-github-apps-permissions). To send pull requests an app will probably need:

   1. **Read and write** access for the **Contents** permission
   2. **Read and write** access for the **Pull requests** permission
   3. **Read and write** access for the **Workflows** permission if you intend for it to send pull requests that change workflow files
3. [Generate a private key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#generating-a-private-key) for your app.
4. Store a copy of the private key in a [GitHub Actions secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) named `MY_GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY`. This can either be a repo-level secret in the repo that will contain the workflow that you're going to write, or it can be a user- or organization-level secret in which case the repo that will contain the workflow will need access to the secret.
5. [Install your GitHub app](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/managing-github-apps/installing-github-apps) in your repo or user or organization account. Take note of the **Installation ID**. This is the 8-digit number that is at the end of the URL of the installation's page in the settings of the repo, user or organization where you installed the app. You'll need this later.

A workflow run that wants to authenticate as your app needs to get a temporary **installation access token** each time it runs, and use that token to authenticate itself. This is called [authenticating as an installation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-an-installation) in GitHub's docs and they give a code example in Ruby. The steps are:

1. Generate a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/introduction) (JWT) with an `iat` ("issued at" time) 60s in the past, an `exp` (expiration time) 10m in the future, and your **App ID** as the `iss` (issuer), and sign the token using your **private key** and the RS256 algorithm.
2. Make an HTTP POST request to `https://api.github.com/app/installations/:installation_id/access_tokens` (replacing `:installation_id` with your **installation ID**) with the signed JWT in an `Authorization: Bearer <SIGNED_JWT>` header.
3. The temporary installation access token will be in the GitHub API's JSON response.

Here's a Python script that implements this token exchange using [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/) and [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) (you'll need to install `pyjwt` with the `cryptography` dependency: `pip install pyjwt[crypto]`).

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import jwt
import requests

def get_token(app_id, private_key, installation_id):
    payload = {
        "iat": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(seconds=60),
        "exp": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=10),
        "iss": app_id,
    }

    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm="RS256")

    response = requests.post(
        f"https://api.github.com/app/installations/{installation_id}/access_tokens",
        headers={
            "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {encoded_jwt}",
        },
        timeout=60,
    )

    return response.json()["token"]

def cli():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--app-id", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--private-key", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--installation-id", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    token = get_token(args.app_id, args.private_key, args.installation_id)

    print(token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

https://github.com/hypothesis/gha-token is a version of the above code as an installable Python package. To install it with [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) and get a token:

```
$ pipx install git+https://github.com/hypothesis/gha-token.git
$ gha-token --app-id $APP_ID --installation-id $INSTALLATION_ID --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY
ghs_xyz***
```

You can write a workflow that uses gha-token to get a token and authenticate any API requests or GitHub CLI calls made by the workflow. The workflow below will:

1. Install Python 3.11 and `gha-token`
2. Call `gha-token` to get an installation access token using the **App ID**, **Installation ID**, and `MY_GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY` GitHub secret that you created earlier
3. Make an automated change and commit it
4. Use the access token to authenticate `git push` and `gh pr create` (GitHub CLI) commands to push a branch and open a PR

Copy the workflow below to a file named `.github/workflows/send-pr.yml` in your repo. Replace `<APP_ID>` with your **App ID** and replace `<INSTALLATION_ID>` with your **Installation ID**:

```yaml
name: Send a Pull Request
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  my_job:
    name: Send a Pull Request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.11"
      - name: Install gha-token
        run: python3.11 -m pip install "git+https://github.com/hypothesis/gha-token.git"
      - name: Get GitHub token
        id: github_token
        run: echo GITHUB_TOKEN=$(gha-token --app-id <APP_ID> --installation-id <INSTALLATION_ID> --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY") >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        env:
          PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.MY_GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ steps.github_token.outputs.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Make some automated changes
        run: echo "Automated changes" >> README.md
      - name: Configure git
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "send-pr.yml workflow"
          git config --global user.email "<>"
      - name: Switch to a branch
        run: git switch --force-create my-branch main
      - name: Commit the changes
        run: git commit README.md -m "Automated commit"
      - name: Push branch
        run: git push --force origin my-branch:my-branch
      - name: Open PR
        run: gh pr create --fill
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ steps.github_token.outputs.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: OMG what a pain in the *ss!  Please tell me is it simpler now.  I just want to push a tag to the repo once the workflow is done.

Comment: Tell me about it

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. By the way, to get the token, I ended up using https://github.com/tibdex/github-app-token

Answer (score 0):

Based on the work done on [this post](https://dev.to/dtinth/authenticating-as-a-github-app-in-a-github-actions-workflow-27co), I designed a github action that allows you to get a token [from an application](https://github.com/Nastaliss/get-github-app-pat).

However, since you prefer not using an external github action at all, you could use the npm module in the post :

```
- name: "Setup Node.js for npx"
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: '20'
- name: "Obtain GitHub App Installation Access Token"
  id: githubAppAuth
  run: |
    echo "${{ secrets.submodules-app-private-key }}" > /tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem
    TOKEN="$(npx obtain-github-app-installation-access-token \
    -a ${{ inputs.submodules-app-id }} \
    -i ${{ inputs.submodules-app-installation-id }} \
    -k /tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem)"
    echo "::add-mask::$TOKEN"
    echo "::set-output name=token::$TOKEN"
- name: "Checkout with submodules"
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    submodules: 'recursive'
    token: ${{ steps.githubAppAuth.outputs.token }}
```

This still uses an external library though (and requires the installation of node).

The ultimate solution would be to directly write a bash script that does everything for you. You can find such a script [here](https://gist.github.com/Nastaliss/7f8466f59072d744540190721a63672d), you could then use it in your github action like this:

```
- name: "Obtain GitHub App Installation Access Token"
  id: githubAppAuth
  run: |
    curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Nastaliss/7f8466f59072d744540190721a63672d/raw/945f8b28473f0d8cd3f2442dfa08481ff370c62a/generate_github_access_token.sh
    chmod +x generate_github_access_token.sh
    echo "${{ secrets.submodules-app-private-key }}" > /tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem
    TOKEN="$(APP_INSTALLATION_ID=${{ inputs.submodules-app-installation-id }} \
      APP_ID=${{ inputs.submodules-app-id }} \
      SIGNING_KEY_PATH="/tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem" \
      ./generate_github_access_token.sh)"
    echo "::add-mask::$TOKEN"
    echo "token=$TOKEN" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
- name: "Checkout with submodules"
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    submodules: 'recursive'
    token: ${{ steps.githubAppAuth.outputs.token }}
```

Of course you can steal the script and copy it locally, removing the dependency to an external piece of code.
Then commit the file alongside your repository, and use :

```
- name: "Obtain GitHub App Installation Access Token"
  id: githubAppAuth
  run: |
    echo "${{ secrets.submodules-app-private-key }}" > /tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem
    TOKEN="$(APP_INSTALLATION_ID=${{ inputs.submodules-app-installation-id }} \
      APP_ID=${{ inputs.submodules-app-id }} \
      SIGNING_KEY_PATH="/tmp/submodules-app-private-key.pem" \
      ./generate_github_access_token.sh)"
    echo "::add-mask::$TOKEN"
    echo "token=$TOKEN" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
- name: "Checkout with submodules"
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    submodules: 'recursive'
    token: ${{ steps.githubAppAuth.outputs.token }}
```

Do not forget to `chmod +x` the `.sh` file